# Como usar o _ em valores no Twig

Tags: twig

Pessoal peercebi que quando eu passo alguma variavel com o _ no nome no Twig ela da erro fazendo com que eu tenha que remover o _ do nome da variavel para funcionar.

Te como acertar isto?

Ex. no PHP $data_aniversario no TWIG: dataaniversario

Obrigado

Comment: Como você está passando esse valor para a view?

Comment: Do modo simples. return $app['twig']->render('lista.twig', ['passagem' => ['data_aniversario'=>'2000-01-01']); Ai na pagina do TWIG se eu fizer assim da erro: {{ passagem.data_aniversario }} se eu fizer assim funciona {{ passagem.dataaniversario }}